# How can I learn more about the technical information about an onion service? (details in the body)

Tags: onion-services

Sorry for the vague question in the title. I wanted to get to the point without loading up the title with unnecessary information.

Essentially what I'm trying to ask is 2 questions:

1. Logistically, how can I retrieve and analyze the hidden service descriptor of an onion with a standard Linux box? Is there a script of some sort?
2. How can I use a tool (similar to OpenSSL's s_client) to extract the public key from an onion for experimental use?

I'd like to note that I've attempted using proxychains to route OpenSSL's s_client through Tor, but I should've assumed that an Onion Service doesn't speak SSL.

Answer (score 0):

1. Fetch a descriptor

[`HSFETCH`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/control-spec.txt#n1392) is a tor control port command that can fetch a descriptor for a hidden service.

The Stem python library has functionality to do this, it's documented in the [Hidden Service tutorial](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/over_the_river.html#hidden-service-descriptors)

2. The public key is part of the descriptor.

This is [documented in the tor rendezvous protocol specificiation](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/rend-spec.txt#n284).